# Matlab change all values of a row subsequent to a number in a row going below a threshold

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given a matrix, i'd like to go through row by row and find any values that are below a threshold call it T.  After the first instance where a value in the row falls below T, all subsequent volumns in that row should have their value changed to say 0.  This would be easy to iterate over a couple loops, but i'd like to do this via matrix operations because i have 50k rows and 100 cols.

Specifically I'd like to take the following input matrix with T=.5:

1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

and get the following:

1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and again to remind I would like to avoid using loops where possible)

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: Do you want that first value below the threshold to also be set to zero?

Comment: Actually I was just going to make an entirely new matrix.  where the values might be different.  So as long as the value is above the threshold it could be C say and the first value below would be R, then 0 after.  So a better description of output matrix would be: 
C C C C R 0 0 0 0 

C C C C C C C C C

C R 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Not sure how to make the lines there.

Comment: In that case maybe this works for you: `cumsum(m < T, 2) + (m < T)`, here your `C` is my `0`, your `R` is my `2` and your `0` is my `1`?

Comment: Or else `~cumsum(m < T, 2) + 2*(m < T)` to switch the `1`s and `0`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
m(cumsum(m < T, 2)==1) = 0   %// Note that ==1 is the same as just logical(), you can test to see if there is a relevant performance difference for you, otherwise just pick the more readable one
```

Or if you need to preserve that first value below the threshold then maybe:

```
I = [false(size(m,1), 1) , logical(cumsum(m < T, 2))]
m(I(:, 1:end-1)) = 0
```

Comment: I have to run for an hour, but will try this when back.  Thanks so much for the quick reply!!!

Comment: Looking at this now.  BRILLIANT.  I love it.  thanks

Comment: Sadly i cannot upvote because i am a new user.  but in spirit i upvote with all my heart.

Comment: @RyanLewis no problem :) you can still accept it though ;) and you can always come back and upvote in the future should you really want to